# Performance issue (caching) - make calculations from the db faster or store them

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, performance

The problem was slightly changed, but the core stays the same. Here is the problem:

Every time user visits the page, the server pulls up the data from the `Setting` table, process it with php functions and displays the result to the user on the html page this way: `md5(result_string+users_ip_address)`.

The `Setting` table is changed once an hour. As result, `result_string` is changed once an hour.

Unfortunately, it takes some time (10 seconds) to get the `result_string` because of complicated calculations.

What are the options to display `md5(result_string+ip_address)` faster for any user than in 10 seconds?

**Environment**: MySQL, php.

Comment: 10 seconds due to what complex calculations? If `md5` takes that long, your server would seem to have problems.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson md5 function is immediate. The string result_string takes long (10 seconds).

Comment: The obvious choice would be using something like [memcached](http://memcached.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Create a new table or file and save value of result_string in that file/db table.

Step 2: Code which updates settings table, append that code with logic of updating result_string value in file/db table.

Step 3: Change your code to always fetch values from new file/db table.

Answer (score 1):

Add a datetime field to Setting table to store the time of the last update.

Then, in php, set a cookie with the expiring date set to the next scheduled update for your Setting Table (One hour in this case):

```
if ( isset($_COOKIE["result_string"]) ){
   $result_string = $_COOKIE["result_string"];
}else{
   $ip_addres = getIp();
   $row = getRecordFromSettingTable();
   $result_string = md5($row->result_string+$ip_address)
   setcookie("result_string", $value, strtotime($row->last_update)+3600);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1.) If the "result" string only changes when "Setting" table is changed. Always calculate the "result" string then and save to the table.

2.) Otherwise cache the result string by writing it to the disk and only caculate every hour.

```
filemtime($filename)-time()
file_put_contents($filename,$data)
file_get_contents($filename)
```

will be very helpful with that.